# preventDefault does not work after add class to element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to add class on span click which will change the icon but not make the span clickable which is work without adding class.

So..:

```
<script>
    $('body').on('click', '.royalonogy-mobile-menu-link', function(e){
     if(e.target.className=='royalonogy-mobile-menu-dropdown') 
         e.preventDefault();
     });
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

          jQuery("#royalonogy-mobile-menu .royalonogy-mobile-menu-item .royalonogy-mobile-menu-link .royalonogy-mobile-menu-dropdown").on('click', function () {
            jQuery(this).parent().next('ul.royalonogy-mobile-podkategorie-menu').toggle();
</script>
```

This code above works well, it show or hide me dropdown menu items. But now I need to add class `royalonogy-mobile-menu-dropdown-active` to that span element and keep the link not clickable, so I tried this after that event which i want to do after toggle:

```
if (jQuery(this).hasClass("royalonogy-mobile-menu-dropdown-active")) {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("royalonogy-mobile-menu-dropdown-active");
} else {
    jQuery(this).addClass("royalonogy-mobile-menu-dropdown-active");
}
```

but after this I'm clicking on the span and it redirects me to that link which I do not want - `royalonogy-mobile-menu-link` is `<a>` element which contains link and span element (class: `.royalonogy-mobile-menu-dropdown`) with icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable a default action return `false`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.royalonogy-mobile-menu-dropdown', e => 
  $(e.target)
    .toggleClass('royalonogy-mobile-menu-dropdown-active')
    .parent().next('.royalonogy-mobile-podkategorie-menu').toggle() 
  && false
);
```

Comment: it working well, just needed to remove the ; after false

Comment: @MartinOrešanský, oops, yes, a leftover

Comment: @MartinOrešanský you can now also upvote the answers (the arrow up) 